# Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider specify multiple IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, session-state

I am using `Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider` to store session information on Redis. 
The config file is below

```
<!--
      <add name="MySessionStateStore" 
        host = "127.0.0.1" [String]
        port = "" [number]
        accessKey = "" [String]
        ssl = "false" [true|false]
        throwOnError = "true" [true|false]
        retryTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" [number]
        databaseId = "0" [number]
        applicationName = "" [String]
        connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" [number]
        operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1000" [number]
        connectionString = "<Valid StackExchange.Redis connection string>" [String]
        loggingClassName = "<Assembly qualified class name that contains logging method specified below>" [String]
        loggingMethodName = "<Logging method should be defined in loggingClass. It should be public, static, does not take any parameters and should have a return type of System.IO.TextWriter.>" [String]
      />
```

I am able to read write session information on the cluster.
My cluster has multiple IP 3 node cluster with one primary node and other child node.
I am not able to specify other IP in the web config file to handle the fail over situation.

Suppose I have a cluster with 172.29.10.11, 172.29.10.12, 172.29.10.13 where 172.29.10.11 is my primary node so I put this IP in web.config file

```
host = "172.29.10.11"
```

Now in case of failure either .12 or .13 will become my primary node. 
How can I handle the fail over situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. I am posting here in case any one have similar problem.

There are two parameters where you can specify the IP:

1. host
2. connectionString

I you use connection string you need to specify all the property values ex

```
<add name="MySessionStateStore" applicationName = "testapp" 
      type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
connectionString ="172.29.10.11:6379,172.29.10.12:6379,172.29.10.13:6379,ssl=false,abortConnect=False" />
```